# Difference between Device and target android device on AVD

Tags: android, virtual-machine, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to generate an AVD machine for android 4.4.2 but, I found 2 elements: Device and Target, What do I chose on them? and the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device - What model you want to test (like Samsung, Nexus)
Target - api level ( like Android 4.4.2 - API level 19)